# How to configure firewalld with docker 20.10

Tags: docker, firewall, iptables, firewalld

I realized that recently docker add [integration with firewalld](https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/#integration-with-firewalld) and I just want to setup my server using firewalld instead of iptables boring rules and chains.

This is my docker zone output:

```
root@test:~# sudo firewall-cmd --zone=docker --list-all 
docker (active)
  target: DROP
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: br-0a659f93a5b6 br-be2e44b2b069 docker0
  sources: 
  services: 
  ports: 
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

I had run multiple services including Laravel(nginx port binding 80 -> 5050), mysql, etc. with above config. I expect that anyone cannot access to port 5050, 3306(mysql) but unfortunately firewall has no effect and everything is open and accessible from outside.

and this is docker modules
[image: docker modules]

Now How really configure firewalld to drop every request excepts allowed ports?

Comment: Did you find any solutions?

Comment: @Zanna_37 No I couldn't find any solution for this and I use [ufw-docker](https://github.com/chaifeng/ufw-docker) for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

In summary, the solution is:

1. Disable iptables in docker
2. Add masquerade to `public` zone
3. Add docker network interface to `trusted` zone
4. Add ethernet interface to `public` zone

Note that this has security implications.

I wrote an article about it here: https://dev.to/soerenmetje/how-to-secure-a-docker-host-using-firewalld-2joo

Comment: Thank you for writing that blog post! I have been trying to learn enough about netfilter to get firewalld doing DNAT so things work as expected, to avoid the gateway/NAT issue you mention in the post.